# Authorisation error when trying the hotel search api

Tags: authentication, sabre

I am trying the rest api [here](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/hotel/search/get_hotel_search/reference-documentation#/HotelSearch/hotelSearch), I have setup a test user and have the bearer auth token for oauth, when I run the query however I just get the following error:

```
{
    "status": "NotProcessed",
    "type": "Validation",
    "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.SEC.NOT_AUTHORIZED",
    "timeStamp": "2022-05-27T14:46:20.358-05:00",
    "message": "Authorization failed due to no access privileges"
}
```